# Binding ICollection to edit form in MVC asp .NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have two models: `Student` and `Course`. I want to create a simple form that edits a course information, e.g. name of the course, and adds or removes students to/from a course. For this, the `Course` model has the property `public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }`. I create the form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Create Course</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CourseName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CourseName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CourseName)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Time, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Time)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Time)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Students, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Students, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Students)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Students)
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

The form fetches all students to the list without any problem. When I hit the save button and start debugging my application, The details of the course, name and time, are passed successfully to the server, but the selected students are not. Not only this, but when I load the form, if a course has some students in it, those students are not selected in the list. So can anybody tell me what is the mistake the I'm making?

Comment: You cannot use the same name for the `ViewBag` property as you use for your model property (both are `Students`) - rename the `ViewBag` property to (say) `StudentList`. But you cannot bind a list box to a collection of complex objects. Your model needs a property (say) public `int[] SelectedStudents { get; set; }` assuming the value of your options a typeof `int`

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `List<int>` in `Course` Model. So, it can map to it. Selected values from list box will return `List<int>` not `List<Student>`. So, you need to create a `ViewModel` for that if you can not edit existing model.

Below is the sample Course model or viewmodel.

```
public class Course
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CourseName { get; set; }
        public string Time { get; set; }
        public List<int> Students { get; set; }
    }
```